# Why arrays in C++ didn't have member function size() until C++11?

Tags: c++, arrays, methods, c++11

Why arrays in C++ didn't have member function size() until C++11 (std::array) ? What was the reason behind this ? Questions like 'how to obtain size of an array?' are quite frequent.

**Edition**
As plain arrays are inherited from C, what is the reason it doesn't have such functionality ? As we can check type of data in array.

Comment: The reason is that `std::array` wasn't part of C++ until C++11. `std::tr1::array` had a `size()` member function.

Comment: raw arrays have no members, they aren't classes.  Arrays are "primitive" types (ish).  In C++11, the only thing that changed was that a new `std::array` class was added to the standard library, C++03 had a `tr1::array` class for years and years.

Comment: There's a difference between arrays and `std::array`'s. You seem to be conflated the two, and it's confusing. C++ arrays didn't and still don't have a `size()` member function. `std::array's (which are not language arrays, but library arrays) do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C++ (not std::array) are no different from arrays in C. They're just a contiguous region of memory allocated to hold some data (of the same type) in memory.

The type could be primitive data types like int, float, char, etc. or complex data types like structures or classes. Irrespective of that accessing an element of the array is just converted to:

```
base address + (sizeof(datatype) * index)
```

In contrast std::array is a class which overloads the [] operator for array access and has special methods to retrieve the size. It is quite similar to std::vector. Internally these classes might use an array to access the elements, but that is cleverly hidden by overloading the [] operator.

Answer (score 4):

Because they come from C, and C doesn't have member functions (nor is array even a class-type).

Compatibility with C was paramount, because allowing existing C codebases to compile as C++ greatly increased the adoption rate of the language. Mucking with something that works while worrying about compatibility was low on the priorities list, when you've got new language features to design.

In C++11 the language reached a point where all these nice little things got to come into existence. So why not add it *now*? Because C arrays still work just fine and it would be a ton of work to change that. It's much easier to introduce a new container (and a very simple one at that), and that's exactly what happened.

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` is a template class, like the other container classes. Plain arrays still don't have members in C++11.

> As plain arrays are inherited from C, what is the reason it doesn't have such functionality ?

You *can* find out the amount of elements in a plain array, using the `sizeof` operator:

```
int a[10];
std::cout << sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
```

This will print "10". You might be confusing arrays with pointers. Here:

```
int* a = new int[10];
```

`a` is *not* an array. It's a pointer.

Comment: The questioner seems to know all this already. He's asking *why* this is the case.

Comment: @GManNickG That's not how I understand the question, since std::array is new to C++11. It wasn't there in the previous standard, so asking why it didn't have a size() member doesn't make sense.

Comment: Huh? If by "it" in "it didn't have a size() member" you mean `std::array`, we're reading different questions. He's asking why arrays (normal arrays, not `std::array`'s, which he notes are the new C++11 way to implement the concept of arrays) don't have a `size()` member.

Comment: @GManNickG So you think that in C++11 they do have a size() member? They still don't. The OP wrote: "Why arrays in C++ didn't have member function size() until C++11".

Comment: `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)` otherwise it won't print 10 on many platforms.

Comment: @NikosC.: Oh come on, you know full well I don't think that, what a frankly stupid thing to say. Perhaps at worst the OP's wording is unclear, but he didn't just write what you quoted, he also clarified what he means by C++11 arrays with "(std::array)". Regardless, I don't think I have anything to add to our conversation because without clarification from OP we're guessing, though it apparently doesn't cross you that when you read something obviously contradictory that your reading may not be the intended one.

Comment: @GManNickG Well, you didn't say what *your* interpretation is either ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A primitive array is not an object and thus does not have member functions. The `std::array` is a class which wraps an array and thus can have member functions and logic to obtain the length of the array.

If you declare an array like:

```
int * myArray = new int[5];
```

It will have no methods to obtain its length.

Answer (score 1):

C arrays do have a known and retrievable size -- which is accessed by the `sizeof` operator. You appear to be confusing arrays and pointers. We cannot know how large a block of memory a pointer is pointing to anymore then you can tell me how many houses are on my street if I told you I live at 10 Downing Street.

C arrays are really just a special case of pointers. They are directly allocated on the stack, and whilst the original array variable they are declared is visible, the compiler is able to tell us the size of the array. However, arrays frequently decompose into pointers. This may be because it was passed to another method or stored in another variable. When this happens, because the compiler can no longer be 100% sure the pointer is pointing at an array (in all cases, that is), we lose the ability to know the size of the array referenced by the pointer.

Comment: good point, thank you